Manhwa about a girl and her brother living in the mountains but suddenly find a man injured who turns out to be a prince
There is a manhwa my cousin wants to read but can't remember the name of it.
A young lady and her little brother live up in the mountains away from people, the brother goes out everyday/every few days to get food and wood while the sister stays home taking care of the house.
One day, the little brother came back with an injured man he had found. The sister surprised took the man inside, took care of his wounds, and let him sleep on the floor next to her brothers bed in his room.
Later, when he woke up, we found out he was a prince. Turns out he fell in love with her at first sight and he kissed her in the garden of her house. He then takes the girl with him to his kingdom, and the boy goes with some mercenaries (I think) for like a 3 day trip.

Can you clarify if there were any science fictional or fantastical happenings going on in this manga? Reincarnation or magic or ghosts?
